# What is a good resource for non-math managers to learn the calculus behind cost analysis?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, economics

I purchased [*Economics of Strategy, 6th Edition* by David Besanko](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111827363X) which [reviews were overwhelmingly positive](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1043519.Economics_of_Strategy) and indicated it covers a lot of topipcs that interest me in broad terms. However, skimming through while I understand many of the chapters there are some segments that include I believe calculus for varius price, quantity, and production curves. For example:

> Associated with the total cost function are two other cost functions: the average cost function, AC(Q), and the marginal cost function, MC(Q). The average cost function describes how the firm's average or per-unit-of-output costs vary with the amount of output it produces. It is given by the formula
>
> $$ AC(Q) = \frac {TC(Q)}Q $$
>
> If total costs were directly proportional to output---for example, if they were given by a formula, such as TC(Q) = 5Q or TC(Q) = 37,000Q, or more generally, by TC(Q) = cQ, where c is a constant---then average cost would be a constant. This is because
>
> $$ AC(Q) = \frac {cQ}Q = C $$

*Economics of Strategy, 6th Edition, David Besanko. p13*

This math is well beyond my understanding and while I can certainly read the text and gain a lot without the mathematical skills I was wondering:

1. Is this relatively speaking a basic calculus formula that a "first year" calculus student might be able to learn and understand?
2. And if so is there a particular book that focuses on teaching pricing calculations like these for managers that don't have a math background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you give doesn't actually constitute calculus, it is simple "translation" and (pre-college) algebra. What they are saying is that you might have a "total cost function" given in terms of the variable $Q$, $TC(Q),$ that has the form $TC(Q) = cQ,$ where $c$ is some constant (real number, probably positive). *If* this were the case, then by using the formula for the "average cost function," $AC(Q)$ we would get
$$AC(Q) = \frac{TC(Q)}{Q} = \frac{cQ}{Q} = c\frac{Q}{Q} = c \times 1 = c.$$
If, you were given some other total cost function, you would get a different result. Like if $TC(Q) = 5 Q^2$ we would get $$AC(Q) = \frac{5 Q^2}{Q} = 5\frac{Q^2}{Q} = 5 Q.$$

So, no calculus here yet. Although if you need a resource for calculus (just the math, not business), I can recommend the free textbooks at [openstax](https://openstax.org/subjects/math). You could simply do the first few chapters, coming up with examples from the world of business and economics to help make the examples concrete. For instance in the example you have given us, the total cost function can be nearly anything (any function that changes with respect to time, or product quantity or price of components, etc.). If the function you dream up is with respect to time, and starts at zero, the $AC$ function is still the average cost function, given any total cost function dependent on time, $Q$, because you are dividing the "amount" of the total cost by the "amount" of total time. Just like how if you want to find the average speed of a car, you would divide the length of the trip by total time.

If you want a book that will more explicitly lay out the math in terms of business vocabulary, you should probably be looking at "Applied Calculus" books. I only know of one free one available at the [opentextbookstore](http://www.opentextbookstore.com/appcalc/appcalc.pdf). I've never used it, but it looks like almost every other calculus book, and since undergraduate calculus hasn't changed for a couple hundred years, it should be fine :-)

Comment: Since your recommendation wasn't a math for managers textbook could you elaborate, what topic on Openstax should I be looking for?

Comment: I added a little more info, although as John pointed out in his comment to his answer, nearly any calculus book will do, they are all very similar. If you feel that you need a little extra guidance to get through the important parts of these books, I recommend either finding a tutor or a friend you can study along with (super helpful), or watching relevant YouTube videos for the parts you have trouble with (there are many videos explaining these concepts in detail since they are so common).

Comment: Thanks that Applied Calculus text sounds like exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but it is interesting to note that occasionally in advanced mathematics, typically with application to physics, we frame problems in terms of "cost functions" even though there is no discernible business application. It's common when you have equations in terms of energy (like light or heat) and you want to minimize the solution, since nature always tries to spend as little energy as possible. All these worlds are closely related.

Answer (score 1):

That particular example is algebra. You're substituting $TC(Q)$ with $cQ$, and canceling the $Q$'s.

As for calculus, though, you may be able to get fairly far along by learning the integral and derivative of a polynomial function:

$$\int_a^b x^n dx = \frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$$

as well as some basic concepts of dimensional analysis. (For example, if you have a plot of hourly rate (dollars per hour) and integrate with respect to time (hours), then the area under the curve has units of dollars (dollars per hour, times hours).

Comment: Thanks, would you know of a book that covers this type of algebra and maybe the calculus you mention as well?

Comment: Pretty much any calculus book that isn't awful will do this. Or you can hit [Khan Academy](https://khanacademy.org) and learn with videos and online exercises for free.